# Create a parcelable array list

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I am stuck on this problem for two weeks now and i am not going to solve it on my own it seems, so i hope you can help me out.

All i need is a working arraylist that can be accessed normally where it says *entries* in my code.

To be a little bit more specific:

**In the "SecondFragment":**

*Go to the OnClickListener*

There it says `entries.add(new PieEntry(number, nomen));`

**This** is the part where a new entry is made in the arraylist that i fail to create.

**Then in the "FirstFragment"**

It says at the *button2.OnClickListener*

```
PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
```

**This** is where i need to receive the data from "*SecondFragment*"

*AND THAT'S IT*

Nothing more, no other things necessaray to help me out.

Thanks in advance, and my best regards,

*Niklas*

**SECONDFRAGMENT**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static SecondFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    SecondFragment fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentSecond.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentSecond;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    TextView tvLabel2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Alle Objekte hier einfügen (wie textview tvavel2)

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {



            if (editText3.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Item ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            else if (editText2.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Quantitiy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }

            else {

                String nomen = (editText3.getText().toString());
                float number = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());

                entries.add(new PieEntry(number, nomen));

                editText3.setText("");
                editText2.setText("");
                editText3.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And:

**FIRSTFRAGMENT**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;


// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final PieChart piechart = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {


        }
    };











    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {
            getResources().getColor(R.color.violp);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.bluep);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.redp);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.greenp);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowp);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.orangep);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.lightbluep);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.purplep);
            getResources().getColor(R.color.darkredp);

            PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");


            set.setColors(new int[]{R.color.bluep, R.color.greenp, R.color.violp, R.color.redp, R.color.yellowp, R.color.orangep, R.color.lightbluep, R.color.purplep, R.color.darkredp}, getActivity());
            PieData datax = new PieData(set);
            piechart.setData(datax);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (R.string.loading),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            piechart.setNoDataText(String.valueOf(R.string.nodata));
            piechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            piechart.animateX(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);
            piechart.animateY(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);



            }



        });






    return view;
}
```

PS: If i could ask this question better or should not ask at all, let me know. I am willing to become a better community member, thanks.

Comment: where and when is `entries` initialized?

Comment: not yet. that's my problem, where i hope you can help me out :)

Comment: if I understand this correctly, on `button1.onClick()` you want to store something in `entries` and on `button2.onClick()` you want to use the current `entries` for  `PieDataSet` as a constructor parameter? What happens to `entries` after constructor is called? Should it be emptied?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: notthing is supposed to happen with the arraylist after that, it should stay as it is.